# Build error while building Nodejs on Cygwin

Tags: c++, c, node.js, cygwin

I need some help compiling Node source code on cygwin. Every time I try to make the build, it throws the following error message. I am using Windows 8 and Cygwin 1.7.28. I have tried installing YASM. Please help!

```
python tools/gyp_node -f make
make -C out BUILDTYPE=Release V=1
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/vineet/node-v0.8.22/out'

  *LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/vineet/node-v0.8.22/out/Release/lib.host:/home/vineet/node-v0.8.22/out/Release/lib.target:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH; cd ../deps/openssl; mkdir -p /home/vineet/node-v0.8.22/out/Release/obj.target/openssl/geni; ml64.exe /Zi /Fo "/home/vineet/node-v0.8.22/out/Release/obj.target/openssl/geni/aes-x86_64.obj" /c "/home/vineet/node-v0.8.22/deps/openssl/asm/x64-win32-masm/aes/aes-x86_64.asm"

/bin/sh: ml64.exe: command not found

deps/openssl/openssl.target.mk:10: recipe for target '/home/vineet/node-v0.8.22/out/Release/obj.target/openssl/geni/aes-x86_64.obj' failed

make[1]: *** [/home/vineet/node-v0.8.22/out/Release/obj.target/openssl/geni/aes-x86_64.obj] Error 127

make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/vineet/node-v0.8.22/out'
Makefile:26: recipe for target 'node' failed
make: *** [node] Error 2*
```

Comment: ml64.exe is a tool within visual studio

Answer (score 0):

Well, since it's complaining about `ml64`, you have to establish:

1. Do you actually *have* `masm/x64` on your system? It's probably in a directory like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\amd64\`
2. Is your path set up within `CygWin` to reference that directory, so that the executable can be found?

By the error message:

```
/bin/sh: ml64.exe: command not found
```

it's almost certainly one of those two problems.

Comment: I dont have Visual Studio installed. Do I need to install the whole thing or can I get the static binary somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

in fact , you can download a [VC++ express](http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/express/aa718373.aspx) from Microsoft, it is free. and just open a VC++ X86 Command Prompt, then simple execute VCbuild.bat, cygwin is useless in this case.